# specialization of member function of templated class

Tags: c++, template-specialization

there:

What is the result of the following codes?

**foo.h**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<class _Tp>
struct Foo
{
   void print() { std::cout << "foo\n"; }
};
```

**foo.cxx**

```cpp
#include "foo.h"

template<>
void Foo<int>::print()
{
   std::cout << "foo<int>\n";
}
```

**main.cxx**

```cpp
#include "foo.h"

int main()
{
   Foo<double>().print();
   Foo<int>().print();
   return 0;
 }
```

The results are different:

1. when complied by MSVC,

   ```
   foo
   foo
   ```
2. when compiled by g++,

   ```
   foo
   foo<int>
   ```

I would like to get the second result regardless of compilers. What should I do additionally to achieve? If possible, would you give me an explanation about underlying standards or mechanism. Thank you!

Comment: The "result of the following codes" is a compilation error in foo.cxx because it does not contain valid C++ code.

Comment: I've changed mis-typed: void Foo<int>::void print() --> void Foo<int>::print() Would you see again, thanks.

Comment: You just need to declare the specialization in the header file, so that it is visible in all translation units. Add a `template<>
void Foo<int>::print();` declaration to the header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program has undefined behavior.

There are two implementations of `Foo<int>::print()` -- an inline definition that is obtained from the class template definition and the non-inline definition in foo.cxx. A compiler is free to choose either.

A compiler is not required to diagnose that as a problem. Many of them (apparently that includes g++ and MSVC) choose that route for definitions of class templates and their member functions.

To make sure that both compilers choose the implementation in foo.cxx, declare the function in foo.h.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class _Tp>
struct Foo
{
   void print() { std::cout << "foo\n"; }
};

template<> void Foo<int>::print();
```

Comment: Thanks but there's a link errors: _unresolved external symbols_ in MSVC, where as it's OK in g++.

Comment: @DongikShin, my first reaction is that perhaps foo.cxx is not part of the build. If foo.cxx is part of the build, I can't explain the linker error.

Answer (score 0):

It is interest. I know that templates are interpreted at compile time, not link time. So, in my opinion, specialization template should implements at each cpp files. What is your g++ version?

Answer (score 0):

If the **foo.h** looks like following, both compilers produce the same results. But I don't know why.

```
#include <iostream>


template<class _Tp>
struct Foo
{
   void print();
};

template<class _Tp>
void Foo<_Tp>::print()
{
   std::cout << "foo\n";
}

template<> void Foo<int>::print();
```